# SQL Server execution plan in FME

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan, fme

I would like to use FME to handle an execution plan from SQL Server (I trying to get a table with a row for each field which is used within a query).

The `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON` function has to be run in it own batch. The normal way would be to us the `GO` operator, however this is not part of T-SQL but is normally interpreted by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and therefore the FME SQL interpreter does not understand it. I've tried running 'SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON` in one SQLExecutor transform followed by the query in the next SQLExecutor, but each transform seems to create its own connection meaning that the Showplan setting doesn't persist from one transformer to the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a brainwave and have managed to use the python transformer to run it using `pyodbc`. This can execute queries in their own batch, whilst maintaining a single connection. My Python Caller tramsformer goes like this:

```py
import fmeobjects
import pyodbc

class FeatureCreator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        
    def input(self,feature):
        newFeature = fmeobjects.FMEFeature()
        
        connectionStr = f"DRIVER={{SQL Server}};SERVER={FME_MacroValues['Server']};Trusted_Connection=yes;"
        if FME_MacroValues['Database'] != '':
            connectionStr += f"DATABASE={FME_MacroValues['Database']};"
        connection = pyodbc.connect(connectionStr)
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        cursor.execute("SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON;")
        cursor.commit()
        cursor.execute(feature.getAttribute('query'))
        
        results = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
        newFeature.setAttribute("showplan", results)
        
        self.pyoutput(newFeature)
        
    def close(self):
        pass
```